# How to override a program that doesn't remember last window dimensions, position?

Tags: windows-10, window, foobar2000, snap

My Foobar2000 doesn't want to remember the window position and dimensions, whenever I start the program again I need to snap the window again. Minor annoyance in an otherwise perfect HTPC, sure, but I'm sure there is a solution...?

Comment: try holding CTRL while closing the window in its correct position. Should store the location settings in the registry. Do note that a maximized state cannot be saved, but if you want to open a window maximized, you can edit the shortcut and set it to launch maximized.

Comment: @LPChip This did not do the trick, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If an application is "portable", i.e., saves state data to a local file, rather than the registry, it might not have permission to write to a file in the *Program Files* or *Program File (x86)* folder.

There are some work-arounds:

- Run the app as Administrator, at least one time, to save screen parameters on closing. Those will persist until run as Admin again.
- Change file permissions on the application's folder, i.e., take possession.
- Move the application to another folder, e.g., *Program Data*.

There are some risks with these approaches if the app is malware, of course.

Comment: Not portable, and problem persists even if logged in as administrator.